# OverrideComponent with TestBed

Tags: angular, components, overriding, testbed

I have `MainComponent` that uses `ChildComponentA` as a `@ViewChild`. `MainComponent` is calling a method on `ChildComponentA`.

I want to write an unit test case mocking `ChildComponentA`. How can I do this using `TestBed` (in Angular 2 RC5)?

Before I used to use `overrideDirective(MainComponentName, ChildComponentA, MockChildComponentA);` Is there an equivalent to this using `TestBed`?

I tried using

```
TestBed.overrideComponent(ChildComponentA,{
        set: {
          template: '<div></div>'
        }
      });
```

which just sets the template, but I want to mock the methods in the component as well.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think in this case you can try and replace the child component with a mock component. Just create a mock component with the same selector and use TestBed to remove the declaration of the real child component and add the declaration to your mock component.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'child',
  template: '<div></div>'
})
class MockComponent {

}
```

And in your test do this to use the mock component:

```
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        imports: [MyModule],
        declarations: [ParentComponent, MockComponent]
    });

    TestBed.overrideModule(MyModule, {
        remove: {
            declarations: [ParentComponent, ChildComponent],
            exports: [ParentComponent, ChildComponent]
        }
    });
```

More details here: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/10689.
Make sure to re-declare the ParentComponent, it does not work otherwise (not sure why).

If you use @ViewChild to get a reference to the child component, you will need to modify it to not use the type of the component, but an id. Use @ViewChild('child') instead of @ViewChild(ChildComponent). See second example from here: http://learnangular2.com/viewChild/

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have configured the TestBed.configureTestingModule with the mockComponent as you mentioned, but didn't overrideModule and still works. I didn't import the MyModule.

Comment: Yes, the override example was there just in case you want to reuse the production ngModule in your tests.

Comment: I have a similar case, but I'm testing a service, which uses a component. I want to mock that component. I tried this, but it does not work. When I run the tests, I get "Error: No component factory found for XComponent". Any Ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Notice that if the `ChildComponent` is being declared in the TestModule itself, there is no need to override the module where the original was declared.

So, if your TestBed declaration looks like this:

```js
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    declarations: [
        ParentComponent,
        ChildComponent         // This is what you'd like to mock
    ]
});
```

Then, to override `ChildComponent` all you need is:

```js
@Component({
    selector: 'child',
    template: '<div></div>'
})
class MockChildComponent {
}

TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    declarations: [
        ParentComponent,
        MockChildComponent      // Notice the original is replaced by the mock
    ]
});
```

As long as `ChildComponent` and `MockChildComponent` have the same selector, this one should work.

The other answer given for this question works for the cases the `ChildComponent` is being brought *from* a different module *into* the TestBed.

#### Note

If your `ChildComponent` has any `@Input` or `@Output`, then include those too in your `MockChildComponent`.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I did with Angular 16 and standalone components:

```
@Component({
  standalone: true,
  selector: 'child',
  template: '<div></div>'
})
class MockComponent {
}
```

and then:

```
await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  ...
}).overrideComponent(ParentComponent, {
  remove: {imports: [ChildComponent]},
  add: {imports: [MockComponent]}
}).compileComponents();
```